Is it halal or haram
im working at the studio that makes Southpark there's a scene where I animate someone doing haram things and I get paid doing it should I find another job

I have flagged your question for moderator invention. You are right to ask this, but this site is flooded with similar questions and I'm looking for some general way for an answer that matches at least most of them. With modern computers, there is a flood of possibilities of what you can do, some halal, some haram.
